# Give a sequential number for each GROUP BY values

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a temp table with many rows (#TümDATA). I `INSERT` it's rows into another temp table (#GrupTOT) with `GROUP BY` clause. But I'm stuck here, I need to give the rows a sequential number after they are GROUPED.

Here is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO #GrupTOT(AY, BLK, DRE, TOT) 
SELECT J.AY, J.BLK, J.DRE, SUM(J.BORÇ) 
FROM #TümDATA J 
GROUP BY J.AY, J.BLK, J.DRE
```

Comment: show us the sql you currently have please

Comment: here used this; INSERT INTO #GrupTOT(AY, BLK, DRE, TOT)
  SELECT J.AY, J.BLK, J.DRE, SUM(J.BORÇ)
    FROM #TümDATA J
  GROUP BY J.AY, J.BLK, J.DRE

Comment: Moved sample SQL to the question and also updated my answer based on the provided SQL

Comment: Tanner, thnx for moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `SELECT INTO` using an `IDENTITY` column. This will create the new temporary table `#GrupTOT`.

Here is a **[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efc349/14)**.

```
SELECT SeqNo = identity(int,1,1), --Identity column
       AY = J.AY
       BLK = J.BLK, 
       DRE = J.DRE,
       TOT = SUM(J.BORÇ) 
INTO #GrupTOT
FROM #TümDATA J 
GROUP BY J.AY, J.BLK, J.DRE;

--SELECT * FROM #GrupTOT
```

Comment: hi Kaf, thnx your answer. This applicable for my sp. Can you answer the additional questions please? What is your solution If sequential value starting came from another table?

Comment: Do you mean sequential number starting value as a variable?

Comment: Yes, a value came from another table column (Table C).

Comment: Declare a variable and get that value assigned to it first, then use it with `row_number()` function [like in this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efc349/22).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get a number based on an `ORDER BY`. Or you could add an [`IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column to autoincrement a number on insert if that is what you want.

The `ROW_NUMBER` approach:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Count(*) as [COUNT]
    FROM dbo.Table1
    GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2
    SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3, [COUNT] DESC ),
           Col1, Col2, Col3, [COUNT]
    FROM CTE
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your quick answer. Is there a way any solutions/approach for starting numeric values from the another table (Table C)?

Comment: What means "starting numeric values from another tables"? You could select that value and add it to the Row_Number if that's what you want.

Comment: Thnx for reply but Kaf's answer best solutions for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Works in Oracle)

```
WITH ORDERS
    AS (SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '2013-09-18 00:00:01',
                     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
                 AS THE_DATE,
             'John' AS NAME
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '2013-09-19 00:00:01',
                     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
                 AS THE_DATE,
             'James' AS NAME
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '2013-09-20 00:00:01',
                     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
                 AS THE_DATE,
             'John' AS NAME
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '2013-09-20 00:00:02',
                     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
                 AS THE_DATE,
             'John' AS NAME
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '2013-09-20 00:00:03',
                     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
                 AS THE_DATE,
             'John' AS NAME
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '2013-09-20 00:00:04',
                     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
                 AS THE_DATE,
             'John' AS NAME
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '2013-09-21 16:00:01',
                     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
                 AS THE_DATE,
             'Jennifer' AS NAME
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      THE_DATE,
      NAME,
      ROWNUM
FROM
      (SELECT
            TRUNC ( THE_DATE ) THE_DATE,
            NAME,
            COUNT ( 1 )
       FROM
            ORDERS
       GROUP BY
            TRUNC ( THE_DATE ),
            NAME);
```

Original Data:

```
9/18/2013 12:00:01 AM   John
9/19/2013 12:00:01 AM   James
9/20/2013 12:00:01 AM   John
9/20/2013 12:00:02 AM   John
9/20/2013 12:00:03 AM   John
9/20/2013 12:00:04 AM   John
9/21/2013 4:00:01 PM    Jennifer
```

Result:

```
9/21/2013   Jennifer    1
9/19/2013   James           2
9/20/2013   John            3
9/18/2013   John            4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186734.aspx) function.

E.g.

```
WITH q AS (
    SELECT field_a
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY field_a
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY field_a) AS row_num,
       field_a
FROM q
```

Comment: Thnx for reply but Kaf's answer best solutions for me.